# How to boost linked documents in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

Is it possible to boost found documents based on other found documents?

E.g. if I have document A which has a link to document B and both are found independently, then to boost them both? By link I mean a field with an ID of another document.

Currently I'm doing it "manually" i.e. I post-process the TopDocs looking for documents that have links to other documents in the same result and move those to the top. This is not the best solution as the TopDocs itself is already limited without taking my custom boosting into account.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to implement a custom lucene collector or extend an existing one. This way you can store all the doc ids which are retrieved and you can post process them all at the end. Depending on the links between your documents, you may be able to throw away some of the docs during the "collecting" phase which will save you memory.